# How can I generate access keys in the wso2 API Store?

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, openam

API Store - Error

**Configured WSO2 to take in an external identity service provider**

**Logging into the store with the oidc configurations redirecting a user to a different login page**

> API Store - ErrorError occurred while executing the action generateApplicationKey

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : DannyApp_PRODUCTION

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException: APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.handleException(APIUtil.java:1507)

[2019-01-23 15:59:43,414] ERROR - APIUtil Error occurred while creating ServiceProvider for app Danny Developer_DannyApp_PRODUCTION

org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.IdentityApplicationManagementException: Already an application available with the same name.
```

Comment: You see the same error when you generate keys for a newly created apps too?

Comment: Yeah, the exact same

Comment: Check the database you have configured with wso2 in master-datasource.xml & look for the table AM_SUBSCRIPTION and AM_APPLICATION. There might be some duplicate entries which got added.